# add time with minutes and the total time spend in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I can't seem to find any related topics about adding two different time which is time in and time out, or maybe I don't get it at all. On how I should calculate the time in and time out using vb.net, With minutes and 1hr break. I just assume that this is the best way to add time in and time out, but it has no total in minutes. I also need to calculate all the total spend time. So how do I code and calculate it?

The code above is from my printing form

```
try
            For row As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1


                Dim value As Integer

                e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value, f14, Brushes.Black, 0, 130 + row * 20)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(1).Value, f14, Brushes.Black, 65, 130 + row * 20)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value, f14, Brushes.Black, 165, 130 + row * 20)


                value = Val(DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(1).Value.ToString) - Val(DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value.ToString)
                value = Math.Abs(value)



                    If DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(1).Value.ToString Is Nothing Then
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("", f14, Brushes.Black, 250, 120 + row * 20)
                    ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value.ToString Is Nothing Then
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("", f14, Brushes.Black, 250, 120 + row * 20)
                    ElseIf value = 0 Then
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("", f14, Brushes.Black, 250, 120 + row * 20)
                    Else
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(value, f14, Brushes.Black, 250, 130 + row * 20)
                    End If
            Next
```

the format of my time is

```
Dim time As String = "HH:mm"
dt.ToString(Time)
```

and then the data is from my mysql database so I

Comment: Time in and time out of what? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, rather than expecting us to work it out from code that doesn't actually do what you want to do. I have no idea what that printing code has to do with anything.

Comment: sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The problem of mine is solved here is my final code:

```
 Dim newrow As New DataGridViewRow()
                newrow.CreateCells(DataGridView1)
                newrow.Cells(0).Value = row

                Dim dayDataRow As DataRow() = table.Select("Day = '" & row & "'")

                If dayDataRow.Length > 0 Then
                    'DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row, dayDataRow(0)("Time_in"), dayDataRow(0)("Time_out"))
                    ' Calculate time spent
                    Dim starttime As TimeSpan
                    Dim endtime As TimeSpan

                    Dim in_time = TimeSpan.TryParse(dayDataRow(0)("Time_in").ToString(), starttime)
                    Dim out_time = TimeSpan.TryParse(dayDataRow(0)("Time_out").ToString(), endtime)
                    Dim timespent As TimeSpan = endtime.Subtract(starttime)
                    Dim adjustedTimeSpent As TimeSpan = timespent.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
                    totalTimeSpent = totalTimeSpent.Add(adjustedTimeSpent)



                    newrow.Cells(1).Value = dayDataRow(0)("Time_in")
                    newrow.Cells(2).Value = dayDataRow(0)("Time_out")
                    newrow.Cells(3).Value = adjustedTimeSpent.ToString()
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(newrow)



                Else
                    'DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row, "", "")
                    'newrow.Cells(3).Value = ""
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row, "", "", "")
                End If
```

this is a new code which it sums the time in, time out and it has the total spend time. I also add 1hr break for lunch time

```
Dim adjustedTimeSpent As TimeSpan = timespent.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
                    totalTimeSpent = totalTimeSpent.Add(adjustedTimeSpent)



                    newrow.Cells(1).Value = dayDataRow(0)("Time_in")
                    newrow.Cells(2).Value = dayDataRow(0)("Time_out")
                    newrow.Cells(3).Value = adjustedTimeSpent.ToString()
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(newrow)
```

here is the snapshot of the output in my datagridview

[image]